# Alternative to ActionFilterAttribute in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to authenticate users in my asp.net core 2.2 application. This is how we use to do it in asp.net web api using .net 4.5

```
public class AuthFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
          //based on certain condition
filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    } 

}
```

I am looing to achieve same in asp.net core 2.2. Only change is, **I need to implement this logic only for few routes. So basically I need to check the route first and then authenticate users only for those roytes**. This is what I found so far:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider : AuthenticationSchemeProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetRequestSchemeAsync()
    {
        var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request;
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The HTTP request cannot be retrieved.");
        }

        // For API requests, use authentication tokens.
        if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
        {
            return await GetSchemeAsync(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // For the other requests, return null to let the base methods
        // decide what's the best scheme based on the default schemes
        // configured in the global authentication options.
        return null;
    }


}
```

**I am not sure how to implement this "GetSchemeAsync". I am also not sure what I am trying to achieve is the right way or not**

Answer (score 1):

Use the Authorize attribute on your controllers action where your need to authorize a user [read the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

If you it want to be more global, you can use an [Authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authorization-filters)